# Is it possible to do an update using SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame, that I created out of parquet file.

```
val file = "/user/spark/pagecounts-20160713-150000.parquet"

val df = sqlContext.read.parquet(file)
df.registerTempTable("wikipedia")
```

And now I want to do an update:

```
// just a dummy update statement    
val sqlDF = sqlContext.sql("update wikipedia set requests=0 where article='!K7_Records'")
```

But I'm getting an error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.1] failure: ``with'' expected but
>   identifier update found
>
> ```
> update wikipediaEnTemp set requests=0 where article='!K7_Records'
> ^
>   at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:36)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.DefaultParserDialect.parse(ParserDialect.scala:67)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:211)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$2.apply(SQLContext.scala:211)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:114)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSQLParser$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$SparkSQLParser$$others$1.apply(SparkSQLParser.scala:113)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:137)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Success.map(Parsers.scala:136)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:237)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Parsers.scala:237)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:217)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:249)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Parsers.scala:249)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Failure.append(Parsers.scala:197)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:249)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:249)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:217)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:882)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(Parsers.scala:882)
>   at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$2.apply(Parsers.scala:881)
>   at scala.util.parsing.combinator.PackratParsers$$anon$1.apply(PackratParsers.scala:110)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.AbstractSparkSQLParser.parse(AbstractSparkSQLParser.scala:34)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:208)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$$anonfun$1.apply(SQLContext.scala:208)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DDLParser.parse(DDLParser.scala:43)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.parseSql(SQLContext.scala:231)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.sql(SQLContext.scala:817)
>   ... 57 elided
> ```

Comment: Can't you update the Dataframe directly? Why do you need SparkSQL?

Comment: Yes, I can update the DataFrame directly. The reason I need SparkSQL is that I want to provide the users with interface they're good with, i.e. SQL. It's unlikely that the users will write any java/scala/python code. So, I'd like to hide from the users low-level details like Spark DataFrames, RDDs etc.

Answer (score 3):

Spark tables are immutable so direct updates are not possible. However, if you can change your schema and queries, you can perform the equivalent of updates using append-only operations. The general problem is known in the data warehousing community as a [Type II Slowly Changing Dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_changing_dimension#Type_2:_add_new_row). There is a [Spark package](https://spark-packages.org/package/dhmodi/spark-scdengine) for this, which I have not worked with.

Answer (score 2):

RDD and Dataframes are immutable because the underlying data is immutable. So DML option is not included as part of sparkSQL.